# Android Instant-release build not includes base APK

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

We are preparing to publish instant app apks to play store via "Instant app development" channel for testing purpose.
When we sign instant app (using same keystore used for Installed App), only geting one feature module apk inside zip folder(instant-release.zip) which giving error while uploading to Play Store by complaining "Your Instant App APKs should contain at least one base APK"

Anyway we able to see the expected structure under instant-debug version

Structure deference between debug and release version as below

## instant-debug.zip

- hello-debug.apk
- base-debug.apk
- bye-debug.apk

## instant-release.zip

- hello-release.apk

And not sure whether we making any mistake on gradle configuration. It will very helpful if anyone can advise on this ?

Comment: You may need to post your gradle files and your build command to help troubleshoot this. How are you building your release? Via Studio menus or via command line assembleRelease?

Comment: Thanks @AdamK , we trying out the google sample https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/hello-feature-module and gradle structure same as this. Also we signing the instant build via Android Studio 3.0 menu.

Comment: There are some known issues signing using the menus in Android Studio. Can you try setting up signingConfigs in your build.gradles and then running assembleRelease from command line or from the gradle menu in Studio (one on the right side). Here's some info on setting up signingConfigs: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-shared-keystore

Comment: You are right @AdamK, we able to generate instant-release.zip with the expected structure using signingConfigs and assembleRelease command. Seems Installed app signing works with android studio menu and Instant app signing not working with that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad it worked. I just copied my comment to an answer below in case others run into the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some known issues signing Instant Apps using the built-in menus in Android Studio 3.0 Preview. If you set up `signingConfigs` in your `build.gradle` files then run `gradle assembleRelease` from command line or from the gradle menu in Studio (one on the right side) it should work.

`signingConfigs` should be setup in each of your feature modules to ensure all feature `APKs` are signed.

Here's some info on setting up `signingConfigs`:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/

Comment: This worked for us, we have added signingConfigs for all feature and base modules' gradle files. Then executed assembleRelease gradle command instead of Android Studios' default signing options. It has created instant-release.zip with all required apks.

Comment: Instant apps can now be successfully signed via the built-in Generate Signed APK in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign all the modules including the baseFeature module separately. Sign all of them by going in their gradle file. I was getting the same error then I signed all the modules and it worked for me.