# You should specify at least one URL in your Instant App APKs manifest Play Store

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Whenever I upload my base and feature APK to Play Store I got that message
I have allready but it in Zip and now I have base but now asking for URL not Base
You should specify at least one ***URL*** in your Instant App APKs manifest.
this my manifest i have tried to but data meta but same issue 
where do I specify the URL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="طبيبنا"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.tabebona.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />

    <activity android:name=".DoctorsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".DoctorDetailsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ContactUSActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".profileActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".DoctorClassbyName" />
    <activity android:name=".SearchNameActivity" />


    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
</application>
```

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415839/upload-failed-your-instant-app-apks-should-contain-at-least-one-base-apk

Comment: This is different from https://stackoverflow.com/q/44415839/8185318.  Your intent filter must support both "http" and "https".  The Play Store currently ignores filters which don't support both, which is why it claims your app has no routes.

Comment: Small correction to my previous comment.  You need these too,

      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

as documented here: https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/prepare.html#default-url